# Open current editing file in explorer tree

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is a **shortcut** for VS Code that **highlights** in solution explorer tree current opened file. Like we have in Visual Studio:

```
Alt + Shift + L
```

Answer (score 89):

Couldn't live with no complete answer, so figured out the following:

**Without a direct keyboard shortcut:**

1. Open the command palette via <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then <kbd>></kbd>) and type `Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar`.
2. This reveals the active file in the side bar similar to Visual Studio's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

**Then, take the above and map a keyboard shortcut to it:**

3. Open keyboard shortcut preferences file via <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> followed by `Preferences: Open Keyboard Preferences File`.
4. Add in the following (taking Visual Studio's lead, I've personally mapped it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, but map to what you want).

```js
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults      
[
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+l",
    "command": "workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer",
  },
]
```

<s>Note that it's not as good as Visual Studio, Atom, etc. in that you can't then navigate with arrow keys in the tree (arrow keys navigate the active file contents), but I guess I'll eventually figure out how to do that.</s>

@Tomoyuki Aota points out that you can do the following to navigate with arrow keys:

> After Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar, press Ctrl+Shift+E (Show
> Explorer). After that, I can navigate the files in the explorer by the
> arrow keys.

Comment: did you figure out how to be able to then use the arrow keys to 'walk through' the file structure?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :-(

Comment: what about "reveal && select the active file"

Comment: @JJS are you asking if there's that option or providing a solution?

Comment: @Ted I was asking if it was an option. My initial testing didn't show that the current file was highlighted, but it actually is.

Comment: @JJS Yep. It is highlighted. But it's still painfully lacking on the "navigate with keyboard following".

Comment: Awesome. I wanted to bind this action to the same combination as in Atom: on a Mac, it's "Cmd+Shift+\\" (Atom shows it as "Cmd+|")

Comment: @Ted @TweeZz After `Files: Reveal Active File in Side Bar`, press Ctrl+Shift+E (Show Explorer). After that, I can navigate the files in the explorer by the arrow keys.

Answer (score 76):

I don't think there's a command for that, but there is a shortcut to enable/disable revealing the current file as you open it:

`"explorer.autoReveal": true`

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

Together with @Rob's correct answer:

```
"explorer.autoReveal": true
```

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>  (Show explorer) focuses that file in the explorer and the `arrow` keys will navigate up/down/left/right like any list.  This works even if the explorer is closed prior to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> has the added bonus in that it will toggle focus between the highlighted file and its editor as well.

For mac, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>

Comment: This is the one I was looking for

Answer (score 18):

Right-click the file tab (not necessarily current one) and click "Reveal in Side Bar".

[image]

Comment: Best answer. Stop it doing it automatically with autoreveal: false and then use context menu when you need to find it Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

F1 then type "reveal" also works from in VS Code, at least for me.

Comment: The command is 'File: Reveal Active File in Side Bar'

Answer (score 5):

I was able to achieve this by customizing the `workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer` command with keybinding <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

1. Open the Keyboard Shortcuts <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. search for focusFilesExplorer command & customize
3. Provide your keybindings that you are used to - I set mine to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the actual version of VS Code offers a command for this feature now.
In the settings, type `revealInExplorer` in the search bar to find the command. There is no default keybinding, so just put your own. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Download the [open in browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=techer.open-in-browser) extension, that's it.
Right click > Open in primary/secondary browser function appears, and the `ALT+B` / `ALT+SHIFT+B` shortcuts become available.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar case and ended up here looking for help.

I opened a file in "preview" mode after clicking a link in a .md file and wanted to know where this opened file was located in the project.

I found this button in the upper right corner of VS Code which was exactly what I wanted:

[image: show source]

It's called "show source"

Answer (score 0):

Also check "Explorer: Auto Reveal Exclude" patterns in VS Code settings.

[image: "Explorer: Auto Reveal Exclude" snapshot]

Files that fit any of the patterns will not be auto revealed in the Explorer tree.